# How to call two tags at same time on active: to make changes in css

Tags: css

I'm having a little problem. As, I'm currently working on a left side menu, and am trying to call the two tags `li` and `a` at the same time on `:active` in css. I searched a lot but couldn't get anything working for me. What I want is to change the color of the whole row of `li` and `a` on `:active` (when the user clicks on the button).

Here is my code:

```css
.sub-menu li,
a:active {
  color: #f1f1f1 !important;
  background-color: #2e8fda !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-list">
  <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
    <li data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed">
      <a><i class="<?=$MainObj['Icon'];?>" style="color:#9f9e9e !important"></i><?=$MainObj['GroupMenuName'];?> <span class="arrow" style="color:#9f9e9e !important">
    </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="a">
        <li><a href="#">check1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">check2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">check3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">check4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" style="color:#9f9e9e !important"></i> Profile
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" style="color:#9f9e9e !important"></i> Users
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="collapse-expand" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1815="1815"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine and it changes all tags. You have to explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: it is not working as I want to chane the color of text of tag a to White whether I click on a, or li

Comment: You can change `.sub-menu li` to `.menu-content li:active`.

Comment: and What about tag a ?? @RacilHilan its color also change ?? and the other thing which i see is that i can only click on the words But I want to click on the whole row.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your `:active` *pseudo-state* rule on the containing parent list item element, then just allow your nested anchor tag to `inherit` the styles of the parent.

```
.sub-menu li:active {
  color: #f1f1f1 !important;
  background-color: #2e8fda !important;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```css
.sub-menu li:active {
  color: #f1f1f1 !important;
  background-color: #2e8fda !important;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-list">
  <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
    <li data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed">
      <a><i class="<?=$MainObj['Icon'];?>" style="color:#9f9e9e !important"></i><?=$MainObj['GroupMenuName'];?> <span class="arrow" style="color:#9f9e9e !important">
    </span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="a">
        <li><a href="#">check1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">check2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">check3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">check4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" style="color:#9f9e9e !important"></i> Profile
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" style="color:#9f9e9e !important"></i> Users
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="collapse-expand" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1815="1815"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. and Inherit means it will run automatically on call ??? and how to include more than one classes in css and also what if I have font on left side of a tag in seperate i tag and I want to change its color to black not to white on active ?\

Answer (score 0):

Is this giving you the result you're looking for? I changed some CSS code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-list">
 <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">                               
 <li data-toggle="collapse"  class="collapsed">
 <a><i class="<?=$MainObj['Icon'];?>" style="color:#9f9e9e !important"></i><?=$MainObj['GroupMenuName'];?> <span class="arrow" style="color:#9f9e9e !important">
</span></a>
 <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="a">
 <li><a href="#">check1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">check2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">check3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">check4</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>

             <li>
              <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" style="color:#9f9e9e !important"></i> Profile
              </a>
              </li>

             <li>
              <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" style="color:#9f9e9e !important"></i> Users
              </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="collapse-expand" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1815="1815"></span>

 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sub-menu a {
  display: block;
}

a:active {
  color: #f1f1f1 !important;
  background-color: #2e8fda !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this help.
**

> ## a:hover #b

**
this make on hover #a, #b can change.
instead of hover use *active* as you want.
If this didn't work then try

## a:hover + #b

or

## a:hover ~ #b

this always work for me on latest version of chrome.